# If it always return the same parameter value, is it still considered as a recursive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

For example, for:

```pascal
BEGIN Algorithm(n)
    IF (n EQUALS 0) THEN
        RETURN 1
    ELSE
        RETURN Algorithm(n+5)/(n+5)
    END IF
END
```

`RETURN Algorithm(n+5)/(n+5)` will always be `RETURN Algorithm(1)`, no matter what parameter value my `n` is. Is this still considered a recursive algorithm?

Comment: It recursively calls `Algorithm(n+5)` and this recursion never terminates.

Comment: This seems not to work at all. The recursion terminates _only_ if `n` is a negative multiple of 5, and in this case it will, at the same time, raise a zero division error, and thus terminate with an error or not at all.

Comment: "RETURN Algorithm(n+5)/(n+5) will always be RETURN Algorithm(1)" How so? Do you mean `Algorithm( (n+5)/(n+5) )` or `(Algorithm(n+5)) / (n+5)`?

Answer (score 2):

What if n=-5? You can end with division/0 error!
Meaning the algorithm result will not be always 1.

Answer (score 0):

What determines if a function is recursive or not is wether there is a chance it will call itself **no matter how silly the outcome maybe**.

```
BEGIN Algorithm(n)
    IF (n EQUALS 0) THEN
        RETURN 1
    ELSE
        RETURN Algorithm(n - 1)
    END IF
END
```

This returns `1` for zero and all positive arguments. For negative it may overflow perhaps. Abyway each recursion is dead code since it might as well be:

```
BEGIN Algorithm(n)
    RETURN 1
END
```